# JS - How can I prevent that if the translate isn't finished yet, I can't press the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, transform

When I click the Slider Button, the transform of the Slider changes. This animation lasts 1 second. How can I prevent, that if the translate isn't finished yet, I can't press the button?

```
// Slider Button Navigation
sliderBtnLeft.addEventListener("click", () => {

    // Container Width
    x = slider.clientWidth;

    // Get the Slider TranslateX value
    tempTranslateX = getTranslateX(slider);

    // Check for first Slider Element
    if(tempTranslateX >= 0)
    {
        // Set translate, to show last item
        slider.style.transform = "translateX(-" + (amountElems - 1) * x + "px)";   
    }
    else
    {
        // Set tranlate, to show next (left) item
        tempTranslateX += x;
        slider.style.transform = "translateX(" + tempTranslateX + "px)";
    }
});

// Function to get Translate Value
function getTranslateX(elem) {
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
    let matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.transform);
    return matrix.m41;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button by default and You can make use of [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event) event to enable it once the transition is completed. `requestAnimationFrame` would work too.